# Duplicated item using Firebase Database childEventListener

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i have a very simple chat app. The basic is that in Database a welcome msg is already stored as first message for that chatroom.
On START i attached a onChildAdded listener and the result is as image
[image]

The Database reference is setted in onCreate using 'GET INTENT' which is an extra String with the ID of the owner of the chatroom created in another activity. So the database is like this :

[image]

So in onCreate i got

```
groupChatId = Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras().get("receiverId")).toString();
chatRoomReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserChat").child(groupChatId);
```

In onStart i iterate using onChildAdded to retrieve the messages and put them in an ArrayList

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    chatRoomReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

I iterate like this

```
@Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            chatText = "";
            String identifier = "";
            Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
```

and finally

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String chatBan = Objects.requireNonNull(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue()).toString();
                String chatTextFound = Objects.requireNonNull(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue()).toString();
                String chatTo = Objects.requireNonNull(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue()).toString();
                String chatUser = Objects.requireNonNull(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue()).toString();
                String chatNick = Objects.requireNonNull(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue()).toString();

                if(chatTextFound.equals(specificStringResource)
                        | chatTextFound.equals(otherSpecificString){
                    chatText = "removed";
                }

                chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
                chatMessage.setBanId(chatBan);
                chatMessage.setMessageText(chatTextFound);
                chatMessage.setMessageTo(chatTo);
                chatMessage.setMessageUser(chatUser);
                chatMessage.setUser_nickname(chatNick);
                chatMessages.add(chatMessages.size(), chatMessage);
            }

            displayMessages(chatMessages);
        }
```

My displayMessages method check if the message text contains a specified string in order to exit the Activity after 3 sec

```
if(!chatText.equals("")){
        rvMessage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this));
        adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatActivity.this, chatMessages, chatRoomReference);
        rvMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        rvMessage.smoothScrollToPosition(chatMessages.size() - 1);
        try{
            wait(3000);

                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                }
            });
```

Otherwise it should just

```
else {
        rvMessage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this));
        adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatActivity.this, chatMessages, chatRoomReference);
        rvMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        rvMessage.smoothScrollToPosition(chatMessages.size() - 1);
    }
```

Items in recyclerview are duplicated also when i write a new message…
My Logcat in verbose,warning etc when running app on virtual device is COMPLETELY EMPTY

I know that is quite a lot of code and a long post but as i'm still a noob in Android Studio and coding it's hard to me to be more effective in choosing what to show in order to get the solution.
Be patient and thank You anyway

Comment: You're sharing quite a lot of code, but we can neither know what `chatRoomReference` is initialized to, nor what JSON data exists at that location. I highly recommend reproducing the problem in isolation, and sharing *that* here. For example: can you reproduce it with just log statements, instead of a UI? That will make it much easier for us to reason about. For more hints, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Following this guidance increases the chances that someone can help you.

Comment: @Frank I looked around and it seems the trouble was due to the use of an Alert Dialog in the activity calling the Chat Activity...i have used a simple toast and trouble seems gone away.